# Kotlin - why do I get a KotlinNullPointerException at moveCamera for Google Map

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is my first time building an android application. However, when I run the app on my Virtual Device, it stopped working and keeps crashing after I click twice the button that link to Google Map. The error says something about null pointer exception.

And Output says like this:

2020-12-19 08:48:46.512 15643-15643/com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln, PID: 15643
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
at com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln.MyNavigationActivity.moveCamera(MyNavigationActivity.kt:261)
at com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln.MyNavigationActivity.access$moveCamera(MyNavigationActivity.kt:31)
at com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln.MyNavigationActivity$getCurrentLocation$1.onComplete(MyNavigationActivity.kt:241)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
package com.tech.redesma.logsheetdataassistancepln

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.github.florent37.runtimepermission.kotlin.askPermission
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_my_navigation.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class MyNavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback
//        , LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener
{

    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

    lateinit var mapView: MapView

    private val MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey"

    private val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f

    lateinit var tvCurrentAddress: TextView

    private var fusedLocationProviderClient : FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

    var end_latitude = 0.0

    var end_longitude = 0.0

    var origin: MarkerOptions? = null

    var destination:MarkerOptions? = null

    var latitude = 0.0

    var longitude = 0.0

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {

        mapView.onResume()
        mMap = googleMap

        askPermissionLocation()

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        mMap!!.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraMoveListener (this)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraIdleListener(this)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_navigation)

        mapView = findViewById<MapView>(R.id.map1)

        tvCurrentAddress = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAdd)

        askPermissionLocation()

        var mapViewBundle: Bundle? = null
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        }

        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)

        B_search.setOnClickListener {

            searchArea()
        }

    }

    private fun searchArea() {
        val tf_location =
            findViewById<View>(R.id.TF_location) as EditText

        val location = tf_location.text.toString()

        var addressList: List<Address>? = null

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()

        if (location != "") {
            val geocoder = Geocoder (applicationContext)
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (addressList != null) {
                for (i in addressList.indices) {
                    val myAddress = addressList[i]
                    val latLng =
                            LatLng(myAddress.latitude, myAddress.longitude)
                    markerOptions.position(latLng)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    end_latitude = myAddress.latitude
                    end_longitude = myAddress.longitude

                    mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))

                    val mo = MarkerOptions()
                    mo.title("Distance")

                    val results = FloatArray(10)
                    Location.distanceBetween(
                            latitude,
                            longitude,
                            end_latitude,
                            end_longitude,
                            results
                    )

                    val s =
                        String.format("%.1f", results[0] / 1000)


                    //Setting marker to draw route between these two points
                    origin = MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .title("HSR Layout").snippet("origin")
                    destination =
                            MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(end_latitude, end_longitude))
                                    .title(tf_location.text.toString())
                                    .snippet("Distance = $s KM")
                    mMap!!.addMarker(destination)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(origin)

                    Toast.makeText(
                            this@MyNavigationActivity,
                            "Distance = $s KM",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ) .show()


                    tvCurrentAddress!!.setText("Distance = $s KM")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        askPermissionLocation()
        var mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        if (mapViewBundle == null){
            mapViewBundle = Bundle()
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle)
        }

        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle)
    }

    private fun askPermissionLocation(){
        askPermission(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ){

            getCurrentLocation()
//            mapView.getMapAsync(this@MyNavigationActivity)

        } .onDeclined {e ->
            if (e.hasDenied()){
                //the list of denied permissions
                e.denied.forEach {
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage("Please accept our permission.. Otherwise you will not be able to use some of our Important Features.")
                        .setPositiveButton("yes") { _, _ ->
                            e.askAgain()
                        } //ask again
                        .setNegativeButton("no") { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }
                        .show()
            }

            if (e.hasForeverDenied()) {
                // the list of forever denied permissions, user has check 'never ask again'
                e.foreverDenied.forEach{
                }
                // you need to open setting manually if you really need it
                e.goToSettings();
            }
        }

    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this@MyNavigationActivity)

        try {
            @SuppressLint ("MissingPermission")
            val location =
                    fusedLocationProviderClient!!.getLastLocation()

            location.addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<Location> {
                override fun onComplete(loc: Task<Location>) {
                    if (loc.isSuccessful) {

                        val currentLocation = loc.result as Location?
                        if (currentLocation != null) {
                            moveCamera(
                                 LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                                 DEFAULT_ZOOM
                            )

                            latitude = currentLocation.latitude
                            longitude = currentLocation.longitude

                        }
                    } else {
                       askPermissionLocation()
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (se: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Security Exception")
        }
    }

    private fun moveCamera(latLng: LatLng, zoom: Float) {
        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom))
    }


//    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
//       val geocoder = Geocoder (this, Locale.getDefault())
//       var addresses: List<Address>? = null
//       try {
//           addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location!!.latitude, location.longitude, 1)
//       } catch (e: IOException) {
//           e.printStackTrace()
//       }
//       setAddress(addresses!![0])
//    }
//
//    private fun setAddress(addresses: Address) {
//        if (addresses != null) {
//
//            if (addresses.getAddressLine(0) != null) {
//                tvCurrentAddress!!.setText(addresses.getAddressLine(0))
//            }
//            if (addresses.getAddressLine(1) != null) {
//                tvCurrentAddress!!.setText(
//                        tvCurrentAddress.getText().toString() + addresses.getAddressLine(1)
//                )
//            }
//        }
//    }
//
//
//
//    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraMove() {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraMoveStarted(p0: Int) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraIdle() {
//        var addresses: List<Address>? = null
//        val geocoder = Geocoder (this, Locale.getDefault())
//        try {
//            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation( mMap!!.getCameraPosition().target.latitude, mMap!!.getCameraPosition().target.longitude, 1)
//
//            setAddress(addresses!![0])
//
//        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        } catch (e: IOException) {
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: `mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom))` 

mMap will null until the map is ready and you might get location before map is ready .

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much for your answer sir.. i've just already solved with remove that code line. :D